# Load external script within Ext JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

Within Ext JS 4, I need to load D3 API. I am using the below code

```js
loadScript: function(callback, scope) {  console.log('5) loadScript called');      
  Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js', onLoad, onError);
     console.log('D3 script loaded ');
    },


    onError : function() {
  console.log('On Error');
 },
 onLoad : function() {
  console.log('On Load');
  d3.select('body').append('div').style('position', 'absolute').style('padding', '0 10px').style('background', 'red').style('opacity', 0);
 },
```

However, in browser console, I get the below error -

Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined

Can someone please help me rectify the above code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.onLoad` and `this.onError`, like this:

```
Ext.Loader.injectScriptElement('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js', this.onLoad, this.onError, this);
```

(You can pass the scope too)